# Jquery hover over an image to show caption with transparent colored background on top

Tags: jquery

When I hover over a thumbnail which is wrapped within an anchor tag I would like the caption to fadein with a background color that covers the entire image  regardless of the images size as this will vary.

This is what it looks like before

[image]

and this is how I would like the hover effect to look like.
[image: this is the hover effect]

I have found a couple of plugins but none of them seem to support rounded corners on the overlay

Also here is a url.

http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/all/

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Sat,

There are already lot of plugins built to do this kind of stuff , see these plugins

http://www.net-kit.com/10-jquery-caption-plugins/

Comment: hmm cool, i would like to try to do it without a plugin first. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this one from link above exactly what you want? If not then people may be misinterpreting your question. http://coryschires.com/jquery-hover-caption-plugin/

Comment: its almost there, I have been playing with this exact one but it overlays a bg image which tiles so cannot have rounded corners, also you can't seem to center the text on this one

Comment: Images are boxes, rounded corners are due to transparent pixels. So unless you build a background customized for the amount of roundness you require you aren't going to get that. Background repeat can be controlled with CSS property background-repeat. Title placement can be handled via CSS also. Still don't have a clear idea what you want. You may want to include a before and an after picture with exactly what you expect. From your picture above I'm still not getting it. The fact that no one else has replied to a fairly standard question also indicates that.

Comment: thin I may have figured it out thanks mrtsherman, I will just add padding to the image and then add rounded corners in the css to the div